# Google Apps Script: Apply formatting rule to a spesific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

according to documents: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

But i only want it to be in a spesific sheet called Resultat.

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("resultat");
```

But with this sheetByName, i get :

```
TypeError: ThisSheet.newConditionalFormatRule is not a function
```

code to call:

```
 var ThisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("resultat");
var range = ThisSheet.getRange("C:D") // only want it to select C element.
 ThisSheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
  var rule1 = ThisSheet.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextContains("NO")
      .setBackground("#b3cfb0")
      .setRanges([range])
      .build();    
  var rules = ThisSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule1);
  ThisSheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

Comment: Is that a typo?  you wanted `sheet` instead of `ThisSheet` ? where is `ThisSheet` defined?

Comment: ur right @marios

Comment: @maria https://jsfiddle.net/q8fcsL05/ (unrelated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your script, I cannot understand about `ThisSheet`. If `ThisSheet` is `sheet` of `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("resultat");`, `newConditionalFormatRule()` is the method of Class SpreadsheetApp. By this, the error occurs.

When `ThisSheet` is `sheet` of `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("resultat");`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("resultat");
var range = sheet.getRange("C:D") // only want it to select C element.
sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenTextContains("NO")
  .setBackground("#b3cfb0")
  .setRanges([range])
  .build();
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule1);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

- By above modified script, the conditional format rule is set to the range of "C:D".
- If you want to set the conditional format rule to the column "C", please modify `var range = sheet.getRange("C:D")` to `var range = sheet.getRange("C:C")`.

#### Reference:

- [newConditionalFormatRule()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newconditionalformatrule)

Comment: thissheet is reallt the sheet var, as you mentioned.

Comment: @maria Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.